# angularjs ui-rouetr Error as controller is not Register

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm using ui-router for routing but im getting an Error as controller is not Register

```
<title></title>
 <script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="Admin_MyApp.js"></script>
    <script src="../EmployeePages/EmployeeScripting/Employee_MyApp.js">
<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="Contact()">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

**admin_Myapp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Admin_MyApp', ['ui.router']);
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider      
            .state('Contact', {
            url: 'contact',
            templateUrl: '/Kpmg/AdminPages/EmployeeDetails/Feedback.html',
            controller: 'abc'
        })
    })
```

**contact.js**

```
app.controller('abc', function ($scope) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the code:

1- You need to add the contact.js to the html

2- Your controller must be defined before your state. So here is the correct order:

```
// define your module first
var app = angular.module('Admin_MyApp', ['ui.router']);

// define your controller on the module
app.controller('abc', function ($scope) {
   // your controller
});

// define the state
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider      
        .state('Contact', {
        url: 'contact',
        templateUrl: '/Kpmg/AdminPages/EmployeeDetails/Feedback.html',
        controller: 'abc'
    })
})
```